# How to use HTTP builder within Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use [HTTP Builder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/POST-Examples) to make a POST request in a pipeline script, (do have it in a shared lib where it works via the command line) but need it to work in Jenkins

I am getting the following error when running in Jenkins.

```
No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
```

My script looks as follows

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7')

import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

def gitUpdateStatus() {
  String targetUrl = 'https://api.github.com/repos/myOrg/'
  def http = new HTTPBuilder(targetUrl)
  http.request(POST) {
  uri.path = "myRepo/statuses/commit_id_here"
  requestContentType = JSON
  body = [state: 'failure', description: 'Jenkins Unit Tests', target_url: 'http://test.co.uk', context: 'unit tests']
  headers.'Authorization' = "token 123"
  headers.'User-Agent' = 'Jenkins Status Update'
  headers.Accept = 'application/json'

  response.success = { resp, json ->
    println "GitHub updated successfully! ${resp.status}"
  }

  response.failure = { resp, json ->
    println "GitHub update Failure! ${resp.status} " + json.message
  }
}

node {

  stage('Echo Client JS')
    git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '${JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_ID}', url: 'git@github.com:myOrg/myRepo.git'
    gitUpdateStatus()

}
```

I have seen many posts where the same issue has arisen but I just cannot seem to figure out how this has been fixed, can anyone assist please ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `@Grab` directly in pipelines. You need to move `gitUpdateStatus()` function into  [Jenkins shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). See [Using third party libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-third-party-libraries).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I had already put this into a shared lib but when calling the method Git would not be updated and the function would just fail silently, which is why i thought of trying it within a pipline directly. any tips on how to debug this at all please

Comment: @Richlewis you can debug it using [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit).